# How to run Windows remove command from NAnt?

Tags: windows, cmd, nant

I want to execute `remove` command from inside a NAnt script. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure NAnt works on MS-DOS? I'm not aware that MS-DOS is still maintained - let alone has a .net runtime

Comment: Sorry to call it MSDOS - what I try to explain is the Windows's internal command-line commands like `dir`, `rm`, `ping`, ect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a command called 'remove' in MSDOS.  Did you mean 'rm'?

Assuming you meant 'rm'  here is an example of how to get it to work ...

```
<tasks>
  <exec>
    <executable>$(windir)\system32\cmd</executable>
    <buildArgs>/c "rm somefile.txt"</buildArgs>
  </exec>
</tasks>
```

Comment: I think in MS-DOS there actually was a remove command, but it has been aged since I used MS-DOS

Comment: @Nam what is the error you get?   Try substituting $(windir) with the path to your windows directory.  Try replacing rm with someother command that you know works in the command prompt on your computer.

Comment: It is probably better to use `$(SystemRoot)` instead of `$(windir)`; also, I think you mean `del` or `erase` instead of `rm` :]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete some files, you could try the built-in [nant delete task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

The built in nant `delete` task is best until you have a problem with `node_modules` and the `The specified path, file name, or both are too long` problem

This worked for me

```
<exec program="${environment::get-variable('WinDir')}\system32\cmd">
    <arg value="/c &quot;rmdir /q /s ${Build.BuildFolder}\WebApplication\node_modules&quot;" />
</exec>
```